# VBA autofill last row for two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to autofill the formulas in columns 4 and 5, with the assumption that i do not know which row contains the last piece of data.

**realized i fudged the question, made a slight edit. TIA

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m6SV.png]

Answer (score 1):

Two parts to this:

1. getting a reference to the Formulas to copy, and the area to fill
2. copying the formulas

See inline comments

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim rFormulaToCopy As Range
    Dim FormulaColumn As Long, NumOfFormula As Long
    Dim DataColumn As Long
    
    '~~~ update to match your sheet layout
    FormulaColumn = 4
    NumOfFormula = 2
    DataColumn = 1
    
    With ActiveSheet '~~~ specify the required sheet
        ' Reference the last row of Formula
        Set rFormulaToCopy = .Cells(.Rows.Count, FormulaColumn).End(xlUp).Resize(, NumOfFormula)
        ' Reference the missing formula range, including the last Formula row.
        ' Assign from/to the Formula property to copy formulas (Excel will update relative references)
        rFormulaToCopy.Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, DataColumn).End(xlUp).Row - rFormulaToCopy.Row + 1).Formula = rFormulaToCopy.Formula
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: sir - this worked an absolute treat on my own issue.  I had data from column 4 onwards, but formulae in columns 1, 2 and 3.  changed the starting points and viola.  thanks